# Adding to the location of a pointer in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I have int foo which has the address of an integer in it.
How do I add to the integer that foo is pointing to in one line?

Solution:

```
(*(int *)foo)+=1
```

This is how I handled it.

Comment: Do you mean foo is an int pointer? ie.  `int * foo`

Comment: Please clarify your question with an example.

Comment: You mean you have a pointer value stored in an `int`?

Comment: @larsmans: `int bla; unsigned int foo = (unsigned int)&bla;`. Though I wonder why he doesn't use a simple pointer...

Comment: you do realize that `int` cannot reliable store a pointer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add to the value the pointer is pointing to:

```
int * pointer;
int value;
(*pointer) += value; // parans for clarity, not necessarily needed
```

Comment: No, this overwrites the old value.

Comment: I ended up doing (*(int *)foo)+=1

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = 4;
int* foo = &a;
// and now the one line you asked
*foo = *foo + 2; // a = 6
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are incrementing by one and feel like writing it the shortest way (++*pointer). Example:

```
int i = 0;
int* ip = &i;

cout << i << endl;
++*ip;
cout << i << endl;
```

Output:

```
0
1
```